# Unexpected token Interval Groovy

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm trying to get records that range from now to about a week ago, but I'm getting an error: `unexpected token: INTERVAL`

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM campaigns where DATE(date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()"

def result = Campaigns.executeQuery(query)
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I5n8.png)

Comment: use simple GORM query instead, Campaigns.findByDateBetween(new Date() ,new Date() -7)

Comment: @ChetanHallan, I tried your approach and it didn't work for me

Comment: what exactly didn't work for you?

Comment: I've been able to fix it. Thank you very much

Comment: @larrybuntus, how did you fix it?

Comment: @EtibarHasanov, sorry about the late reply. I use this `from Campaigns where YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW()) order by date asc`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use criteria or where queries?

```
Campaigns.where{date <= new Date() && date > new Date() -7}.list()
```